# Не получается реализовать waypoints в google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Есть задача построить два маршрута от начальной точки до конечной, через промежуточные. Поскольку в JS я полный ноль, начал искать готовые решения... получилось построть маршруты от начальной до конечной точки, но не получается указать промежуточные, если пытаюсь указать то маршрут вообще не строится, проблема возникает в строчке waypoints, если ее убрать то все работает.

```
function initialize() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.904779, 37.541202),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),    mapOptions);
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();



            directionsService.route({
                origin: "55.904779, 37.54120",
                destination: "55.908560,37.597723",
                waypoints: "55.905731, 37.591735",
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function(result) {
                renderDirections(result, { strokeColor:'#ff0000' });
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                map.setZoom(12);
            }, 2000);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно не помню но вроде waypoints принимает в себя массив данных с `location` и необязательным параметром `stopover` а не строку.

```
function initialize() {

        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(55.904779, 37.54120);
        var stop = new google.maps.LatLng(55.908560,37.597723);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.904779, 37.541202),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),    mapOptions);
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();



        directionsService.route({
            origin: start,
            destination: stop,
            waypoints: [
                {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(55.905731, 37.591735),
                    stopover: false // - логическая переменная, указывающая, является ли промежуточная точка остановкой на маршруте. Если является, то маршрут разделяется на два отдельных маршрута.
                }],
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(result) {
            renderDirections(result, { strokeColor:'#ff0000' });
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            map.setZoom(12);
        }, 2000);

    }
```